# How to do an Apache2 rewrite for ip based address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, ip-address, url-rewriting

I have a development server that has Ubuntu server 10.10 with an ip of 192.168.0.175.
When I enable the rewrite mod for apache2 and change the site config to allow rewrite then things get all messed up.

With rewrite turned off and allow rewrites to None then I type in `192.168.0.175/test` and the site loads, but with it all turned on it changes the address to `www.192.168.0.175/test` and the site does not load.

Why is this happening?

Comment: In all likelihood, you have a RewriteRule that takes any address that does not begin with www. and adds it.  If you could post your .htaccess (or relevant config if you're in the main apache2 configuration for your site), we might be more help.

Answer (score 0):

www.192.168.0.175 is wrong. If you type www the browser assumes that is a domain name.

The Ip's should be prefixed with www